# jQuery global keypress event method calling vuejs method doesn't work as expected. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a web page that can display several html style dialogs.  I'd like to have code in just one place that can sense that the enter key was pressed and call the same method as would be called by clicking the OK button for the dialog. This allows visitor to press enter in the dialog to close it instead of having to click the OK button. Pretty simple stuff.

I'd to use jQuery to create a global keydown handler that looks for the enter key and calls the vuejs dlogClose method.  I have created a minimal version of this below.  In real life there would be multiple dialogs and more complex code to find the appropriate dlogClose method for the particular dialog. But I have removed that logic to create a minimal code example of where Vue is not behaving as expected.

Click the button to open the dialog.  Then click the ok button.  It will display an alert saying "dlogClose called" and then it will close the dialog.  Works exactly as expected.

Then click the button to open the dialog again. This time press the enter key. The jQuery global event handler will see the enter key and call the same dlogClose method. That method will display an alert saying "dlogClose called" as expected BUT it's won't close the dialog!  What?  That's totally unexpected behaviour.

Can you explain why this behavior is valid?  Or is this some sort of vue library bug?

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        dlogVisible: false
    },
    methods: {
        dlogClose: function () {
            alert("dlogClose called");
            app.dlogVisible = false;
        }

    },
    created: function () {
        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                app.dlogClose();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.dlog{
    height:200px; width:200px; border: solid 1px gray; 
    padding: 20px; box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px gray;
    position: absolute; top:40px; left:40px; background-color:white
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.5/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

    <div>Global Enter Key Example</div>
    <br />
    <div id="app">
        <div class="dlog" v-if="dlogVisible">
            Pressing enter calls same method as clicking OK button<br />
            <br />
            <button type="button" v-on:click="dlogClose()">OK</button>
        </div>

        <button type="button" v-on:click="dlogVisible=true;">Open Dialog</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that pressing the enter key while the dialog is open also triggers the open dialog button. So in essence, the dialog is closed and the immediately re-opened. Use preventDefault to stop that from happening.

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (e.which == 13) {         
    app.dlogClose();
  }
});
```

Here is the code updated.

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        dlogVisible: false
    },
    methods: {
        dlogClose: function () {
            alert("dlogClose called");
            app.dlogVisible = false;
        }

    },
    created: function () {
        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            if (e.which == 13) {
            
                app.dlogClose();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.dlog{
    height:200px; width:200px; border: solid 1px gray; 
    padding: 20px; box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px gray;
    position: absolute; top:40px; left:40px; background-color:white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.5/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

    <div>Global Enter Key Example</div>
    <br />
    <div id="app">
        <div class="dlog" v-if="dlogVisible">
            Pressing enter calls same method as clicking OK button<br />
            <br />
            <button type="button" v-on:click="dlogClose()">OK</button>
        </div>

        <button type="button" v-on:click="dlogVisible=true;">Open Dialog</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's makes perfect sense.  Wow!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a jQuery event listener in the created () method within the top most page component (the App component).  In that top level app component, make a method to to fire each time the enter button is hit of whenever it meets the condition you specify.  For simplicity, you can then increment a vuex state counter or something.  Whatever child components you have can watch for the counter to change and react accordingly (again based on conditions you set). I am not very knowledgeable about dispatching but that might be another route to investigate.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer my question. See the code I provided.  I am creating a jquery event listener in the vue Created() method to listen for the enter key.  And it calls the appropriate method as demonstrated by the alert.  But somehow it does not execute the line of code in that method after the alert (which is the line that would close the dialog).  What's up with that?  How can that be?

Comment: So you want to assign the same component's data object dlogVisible to false?  If so wouldn't that be this.dlogVisible = false;

Comment: Or app.dlogVisible = false;  Same thing in this case.  Neither seems to execute in dlogClose() if called by the global jquery event handler.  And I've simplified it down so that there are no components involved.  This is a pretty simplistic example and yet it's behavior is not as expected.  How can app.dlogVisible not get set to false when called by the jquery event handler?

Comment: I misread part of your post. Maybe this will work... created: function () { var self = this;
        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                self.dlogClose();
            }
        });
    }

Comment: That's a really cleaver approach. But unfortunately it doesn't work either.  And even crazier, if I use that approach to try to set dlogVisible = false directly in the event handler it still doesn't work.  i.e. var self = this;
                $(document).keypress(function (e) {
                    if (e.which == 13) {
                        self.dlogVisible = false;
                    }
                });  //How can that possibly not work?